# How many stations "is it?" vs "are there?"

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

Recently I've come across the question in a book that says

> How many stations **is it**?

I thought the correct way to ask the question is

> How many stations **are there**?

Can you please tell me which is correct and explain the difference between the two?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide the complete sentence?

Comment: Hello, the question is about train stations, and I am interested to find out if you use "is" or "are"? And why. Thank you

Comment: The answer depends on the context. It can be either.

Comment: 'How many stations are there [on the Jubilee Line]?' shows the default plural agreement. 'How many stations is it before we reach Wigan?' might be considered acceptable, the intervening stations being grouped into a notional single concept.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you need "how many stations are there" to be grammatically correct:

> - How many stations are there on the line?
> - How many stations are there until we arrive at London?

However, it is idiomatic (in BrE) to use "how many stations is it" in certain circumstances:

> - How many stations is it to London?

This has the same meaning as the second example above.

Comment: In fact, I think I would just say "How many stations to London?"

Comment: @TrevorD That would be more colloquial.

Comment: I agree! Substantiating your answer: one could argue that "How many stations is it to London?" is a contraction of "How many stations is *the journey* to London?", with the singular verb matching the singular *journey*. We would also say, "How many *miles is* it to London?" (whether referring to the rail route or a road route); again a contraction of "How many miles is the route/journey to ...".

Comment: @Mick I think TrevorD's point is correct. You have identified the contexts but he has explained the difference. It's not idiom - there are different subjects. in the one case, the stations, in the other, the journey. I think it is worth adding that distinction to the answer to better explain it.